# Richfaces 4 close two popups on oncomplete

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, el

first of, an explanation of what I'm trying to achieve:

I'm opening up a popup panel from a form. This popup has the ability to open a second popup (confirmation) which then calls an action from the server and also closes both popups when the action is complete.

**How can I close both popups after completion of the action (ActionListener)?**

Here are my two examples:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<a4j:commandButton value="execute" 
                   action="#{navigationController.navigateSomewhere}"
                   actionListener="#{beanController.doSomething}"
                   render="datatable,navigationDiv">
     <rich:componentControl event="click"  target="firstPopup, confirmPopup"
                            operation="hide" />
</a4j:commandButton>
```

The componentControl seems to disable XHR calls, is that intended or not?

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<a4j:commandButton value="execute" 
                   action="#{navigationController.navigateSomewhere}"
                   actionListener="#{beanController.doSomething}"
                   render="datatable,navigationDiv"
                   oncomplete="#{rich:component('firstPopup')}.hide()
                               #{rich:component('confirmPopup')}.hide()">         
</a4j:commandButton>
```

It's clear that the second suggestion will not work, also by adding "AND" neither. By the way I'm using **Richfaces 4.3.1** and **JSF 2.0**. After removing componentControl, the XHR call goes through successfully, but both popups will still remain on the display. Here additionally both links to the VDL documentation of the components.

[a4j:commandButton](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/a4j/commandButton.html)

[rich:componentControl](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/rich/componentControl.html)

According to the description of componentControl, my application shouldn't behave this way:

> The  behavior allows JavaScript API functions to be called on target components. The functions are called after defined events are triggered on the component to with the  behavior is attached. Initialization variants and activation events can be customized, and parameters can be passed to the target component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried with the good syntax :

```
oncomplete="#{rich:component('firstPopup')}.hide();#{rich:component('confirmPopup')}.hide();"
```

Comment: Alexandre, nice and thank you. I've trusted my IDE (IntelliJ) too much. It stated an error with "statement expected", which prevented me of just trying it: http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/9986/idead.png

Comment: Mixing EL and JavaScript can do strange things... never used IntelliJ so can't tell much about it but NetBeans doesn't have a problem with that!